# Flask change button state dynamic

Tags: jquery, python, flask

Im trying to understand how Flask works. I followed this example: [example](http://electronicsbyexamples.blogspot.com/2014/02/raspberry-pi-control-from-mobile-device.html)
I was able to enable and disable the system fine. The text was dynamically changes depended on the systems state, but not the button.

I would like to enable and disable the system from a GPIO button and from the web.
Now if I enable the system from the web, and disable it from the GPIO button, the button on the web stays ON, so I have to disable it again and then enable it.

Is it possible to make the button changes to ON automatically(Not the "The system is Armed/Disarmed" text but the actual button)

My code is:

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
h3, h4 {text-align: center;}
span {font-weight: bold;}
</style>

<script type=text/javascript>
    $(
    // When the LED button is pressed (change)
    // do an ajax request to server to change LED state
    function() 
    {
        $('#flip-1').change(function() 
        {
        $.getJSON('/_led', {state: $('#flip-1').val()});
        });     
    }
    );

    $(
    // periodically (500ms) do an ajax request to get the button state
    // modify the span tag to reflect the state (pressed or not)
    // the state text comes from the JSON string returned by the server
    function button() 
    {
        $.getJSON('/_button', function(data)
            {
                $("#buttonState").text(data.buttonState);
                setTimeout(function(){button();},500);
            });
    }
    );


</script>
<!-- Simple JQuery Mobile page that display the button state on the breadoard -->
<!-- You can also change the LED state with the slider switch -->
<!-- The Raspberry Pi uptime is displayed in the footer (Jinja2 expands the template tag) -->

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
  <div data-role="header">
    <div><h3>Raspberry Pi Web Control</h3></div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <form>
    <p>The system is <span id="buttonState"></span></p>
    <br>
    <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" style="float: left;">
        <option value="off">Sys off</option>
        <option value="on">Sys on</option>
    </select>
    </form>
  </div>
 <div data-role="footer">
    <div><h4>This Raspberry Pi has been {{uptime}}</h4></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

web.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import test
app = Flask(__name__)

# return index page when IP address of RPi is typed in the browser
@app.route("/")
def Index():
    return render_template("index.html", uptime=GetUptime())

# ajax GET call this function to set led state
# depeding on the GET parameter sent
@app.route("/_led")
def _led():
    state = request.args.get('state')
    if state=="on":
        test.arm()
        test.write1()
        print test.read()
    else:
        test.disarm()
        test.write0()
        print test.read()
    return ""

# ajax GET call this function periodically to read button state
# the state is sent back as json data
@app.route("/_button")
def _button():
    if (test.read() == "1"):
        state = "armed"
    else:
        state = "disarmed"
    return jsonify(buttonState=state)

def GetUptime():
    # get uptime from the linux terminal command
    from subprocess import check_output
    output = check_output(["uptime"])
    # return only uptime info
    uptime = output[output.find("up"):output.find("user")-5]
    return uptime

# run the webserver on standard port 80, requires sudo
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test.initialize_Output()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: Reading between the lines I think you want the `flip-1` to switch between the two options based on what `_button()` returns. That's all entirely in the browser, and has nothing to do with Flask, really. I am retagging your question with jQuery therefor.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I'll try to figure it out, based on your hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a val() method which can both get and set a control (that's not always true but generally it is - see http://api.jquery.com/val/ for more info). So I think you just need to use val() to update the value of flip-1 whenever you get the button state from the server.

The value used with the val() method needs to match the value attributes of the option elements inside the select element (in the HTML). Your code will be simplest if the state values in the HTML are the same state values used in the Flask code, so I have just updated the HTML and left the Flask code as is.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            h3, h4 {text-align: center;}
            span {font-weight: bold;}
        </style>

        <script type=text/javascript>
            $(function() {
                // When the LED button is pressed (change)
                // do an ajax request to server to change LED state


                $('#flip-1').change(function() {
                    $.getJSON('/_led', {state: $('#flip-1').val()});
                });     


                // periodically (500ms) do an ajax request to get the button state
                // modify the span tag to reflect the state (pressed or not)
                // the state text comes from the JSON string returned by the server
                function button(){
                    var data = ajax_button('/_button');

                    // New line to update button state; and refresh the jQuery mobile slider widget
                    $('#flip-1').val(data.buttonState).slider('refresh');

                    $("#buttonState").text(data.buttonState);
                }

                button(); // Update state on page load
                setInterval(button,500); // And then update every 0.5 seconds after that
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Simple JQuery Mobile page that display the button state on the breadoard -->
        <!-- You can also change the LED state with the slider switch -->
        <!-- The Raspberry Pi uptime is displayed in the footer (Jinja2 expands the template tag) -->

        <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
          <div data-role="header">
            <div><h3>Raspberry Pi Web Control</h3></div>
          </div>

          <div data-role="content">
            <form>
            <p>The system is <span id="buttonState"></span></p>
            <br>

            <!-- Changed these option values to match the values returned by Flask -->
            <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" style="float: left;">
                <option value="disarmed">Sys off - disarmed</option>
                <option value="armed">Sys on - armed</option>
            </select>
            </form>
          </div>
         <div data-role="footer">
            <div><h4>This Raspberry Pi has been {{uptime}}</h4></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I changed a few things:

- select element option values changed from on/off to armed/disarmed to match the Flask state values
- added in html and body elements to html
- moved script and style into the head element
- added the .val() method to set the value of the select element based on state passed from Flask via AJAX
- merged the two JavaScript $() functions into a single function. $() is a jQuery shorthand for, "execute this code once the DOM has been loaded"
- used setInterval() instead of setTimeout() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

This is the jsfiddle in case you want to compare http://jsfiddle.net/LcBQ7/4/

Comment: Thanks Ben, for your replay. I tested your code and it doesn't work, it seems logical though. On refresh, even if the system is armed, the button's state indicates off.

Comment: Does the button state stay off or does it change after the first 0.5 seconds? In your original code, and in the jsfiddle, the function to update the button state in the UI ( "button()" ) only happens after 0.5 seconds passed. You can make it execute straight away by calling "button()" after you have defined the button function. I have updated the jsfiddle to show this.

Comment: It stays off all the time, even if its on, on refresh it goes off again.
Thanks again for your interest.

Comment: I just noticed the values of the select element are "on and "off" but the Flask code passes back "armed" and "disarmed". You will either need to convert between the two state values (e.g. if state == "armed": state="on") or just use the one set of state values. I've updated the answer. If that doesn't work I can only suggest testing the assumptions made in the code by putting "print" statements in the Python code and "console.log()" statements in the JavaScript.

Comment: I found the answer finally, I submit it as an answer. Check it out. Thanks again Ben!

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of Ben's answer and another line. I managed to get exactly the results I was looking for.
The Script on the html file should look like:

```
<style>
h3, h4 {text-align: center;}
span {font-weight: bold;}
</style>

<script type=text/javascript>
    $(
    // When the LED button is pressed (change)
    // do an ajax request to server to change LED state
    function() 
    {
        $('#flip-1').change(function() 
        {
        $.getJSON('/_led', {state: $('#flip-1').val()});
        });     
    }
    );

    $(
    // periodically (500ms) do an ajax request to get the button state
    // modify the span tag to reflect the state (pressed or not)
    // the state text comes from the JSON string returned by the server
   function button() 
    {
    $.getJSON('/_button', function(data)
        {
            //Ben's line in order to change the slider's state
            $('#flip-1').val(data.buttonState);
            //The new line that makes the slider work depending on the state's value
            $('#flip-1').slider('refresh');
            $("#buttonState").text(data.buttonState);

            // New line to update button state

            setTimeout(function(){button();},500);
        });
    }
    );
</script>
```

Im not sure what the new line does, but I suppose it just refreshes the slider state, in order to get the new results.
Thanks for your help Ben. I really appreciate it. Now That I have a solid solution, I can carry on to add for buttons for more functions.

Comment: Well done! This is the API doco on the slider refresh http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/#method-refresh. I've added that to my answer above in case someone wants to copy and paste it